# Does /usr/local/etc read global /etc?

Tags: php, linux, docker, apache, operating-system

I pulled a docker image php apache, then installed some modules via `apt` globally.

- PHP is installed on `/usr/local`
- `php --ini` shows that the configuration file path is `/usr/local/etc/php`, with two files `php.ini-development` and `php.ini-production` under the directory.
- Modules are loaded in `/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d` and `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d`
- There are `php.ini` files in `/etc/php/7.2/cli` and `/etc/php/7.2/apache2`

Problem: php does not load modules in `/etc/php/7.2/cli/conf.d` or `/etc/php/7.2/apache2/conf.d`

My questions:

1. Is local software completely isolated that does not read global configurations at all?
2. In this case (PHP installed in local), is the whole directory `/etc/php/xxx` useless because it is not loaded?
3. What is best practice then? What I am thinking is by making symbolic links to global configurations or installing packages locally if possible
4. Is it recommended installing softwares in `/usr/local` instead of global system?

Comment: Take a look at this post https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/15473/what-is-the-difference-between-etc-and-usr-local-etc

Comment: Can you edit your question to include your Dockerfile?  As an extremely general statement, things in Docker images are isolated from other images and things on the host system, so it's usually easier to install software in the "system" locations; but the exact details of that depend on the specific image you're running.